# Is transfer speed for transfers on local network affected by distance between computers?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, file-transfer, scp

I am currently doing a big `scp` transfer between two computers on my local Wi-Fi network (approx. 80 GB). I am transferring from a laptop running Linux to a stationary iMac. Where should I physically place the laptop to maximize transfer speed? As close to the router as possible or as close to the iMac as possible?

Comment: There are SO many variables when it comes to wireless signals. Plain and simple, distance can make a difference, but only when you are nearing the end range of that particular router. Other things can play havoc as well, and are usually more detrimental than distance when within range of the device. Here are some things to consider: http://www.pearsonitcertification.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1329709&seqNum=3

Comment: @MaQleod OK, but I guess what I really was wondering was: does all traffic go through the router or can the computers transfer directly between them?

Comment: Are both computers on wifi?

Comment: They are, but I realize now that the iMac is both on wifi and Ethernet, and that I used the Ethernet IP address

Comment: Yes, all traffic goes through the router in infrastructure mode.

Answer (score 0):

Overall you are limited by the inverse square law of field strength. Field strength is inversely proportional to the square of the distance - so double the distance, and signal strength is quartered. So based on that, you want the laptop as close as possible to the access point. 
However, there will be an optimum distance where too close is also not good, but it will likely depend on so many factors (such as antenna gain, orientation of the internal laptop antenna etc) that it is impossible to say.

If both machines are on the wifi then you also have the issue of the wifi being essentially half-duplex which would make it slower.

Unless you are running some dope access point that does 802.11AC, I'd say it's going to be a lot faster copying the files over a wired connection, or even to a USB stick first and transfer the files that way.

Comment: Okay thanks for the information. I think my router is 802.11AC though. At least I am getting transfer speeds at up to 100 mbit/s. I asked the question purely out of curiosity about how local transfers work, and about 70% is already transferred so I'm not switching to USB now.